# how to solve a complex function

Tags: estimation, function

My aim is to solve $$-N (\beta  \mu )^{\frac{1}{\beta +1}} s^{-\frac{1}{\beta +1}}-\frac{(\beta +2) N}{2 (\beta +1) s}+t=0$$

The above equation is related to $s$ and the other parameters are constants. Here $\beta>0,$ $\mu>0$, $N>0$, and $s>0$.

I want to find the solution $s=?$.

Clearly it is not easy to solve.  For my problem, $s\to \infty$ and $N\to \infty$, we can just use the leading term of the above equation, which gives $s\sim \left(\frac{t (\beta  \mu )^{-\frac{1}{\beta +1}}}{N}\right)^{-\beta -1}$.

My problem is how to add another term to make the solution a bit better.

Thanks!

Comment: Except for a few special values of $\beta,$ this requires numerical methods and can have multiple solutions.  To see why that is, consider the case where $1/(\beta+1)=p/q$ is a positive rational number.  Since you want $s$ to be large, let $u=s^{1/q}$ also be large and nonzero.  Multiplying the equation by $u^p$ expresses it as a polynomial in $u$ of degree $\max(p,q,1).$ The rest of the analysis is easy.

Comment: If i just use the leading term, the solution $s$ is not good.  I want to find a correction term. @whuber

Comment: I showed you how.  If you want to go further, do one (or a few) Newton-Raphson iterations or expand the polynomial around $\infty.$

Comment: @whuber  Thanks!  I am trying your method.

Comment: The solution with the correction term is $s\simeq \left(\frac{t (\beta  \mu )^{-\frac{1}{\beta +1}}}{N}\right)^{-\beta -1}+(\beta+2)N/2/t$.  Thanks @whuber